# Calculations with auto width

Tags: css

I don't know if is possible to do something like this with pure css. `width: auto - 100px;`

```
element.style {
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: auto;
}
```

I need to subtract the value of 100px to the width, always. This only can be done with JS or there is any css alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes I think in your case you can use the CSS 3 [`calc()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation)

```
element.style {
margin-left: 100px;
width: calc(100% - 100px); /* Just an example */
}
```

Comment: Quick and wrong. Unless the container is less then 100 pixels wide.

Comment: Alot of browsers still require their own vendor prefix tho, like `width: -webkit-calc(100px - 100%);`

Answer (score 1):

No css alternative that is widely supported.

These kind of calculations can only be made in JS.

Although depending on the situation there might be a solution involving, padding & margin tricks.

May you have a concrete example we might be able to help.